# SQL - Need to duplicate rows but with a unique primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to duplicate some rows in a table but the primary key needs to be unique. When I try to do it this way I get a "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint"

```
INSERT INTO Company.Customer
SELECT CustomerId, FirstName, LastName
FROM Company.Customer
WHERE LastName LIKE '%JONES%';
```

CustomerId in this example is the primary key. So the values in FirstName and LastName need to stay the same but the CustomerId needs to change

Thanks!

Comment: Is field `CustomerId` an IDENTITY field? Also is it MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: There's a good reason a primary key is unique!!

Comment: It's SQL Server. In properties it says Primary Key: True, Allow Nulls: False, Is Computed: False, Identity: False, Identity Seed: 0, Identity Increment: 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comments it seems that `CustomerId` is not IDENTITY column. This makes things trickier, because it is unclear how your primary keys are generated. For simple case you can use such approach:

```
-- Retrieve maximum value of CustomerId
DECLARE @maxid int = 0
SELECT @maxid = MAX(CustomerId) FROM Company.Customer

-- When inserting data for column CustomerId add maximum id value and row number
-- This should ensure that the key values do not clash
INSERT INTO Company.Customer (CustomerId, FirstName, LastName)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerId ASC) + @maxid, FirstName, LastName 
FROM Company.Customer    
WHERE LastName LIKE '%JONES%';
```

However, if you don't have a reason not to, I suggest using IDENTITY column - It will make things easier to handle.

Comment: It's in Microsoft SQL. When I do that it says 'Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.'

Comment: Is your table called `Company.Customer` and does it have columns `FirstName` and `LastName`?

Comment: I've changed the labels but it's essentially the same. In properties it says Primary Key: True, Allow Nulls: False, Is Computed: False, Identity: False, Identity Seed: 0, Identity Increment: 0

Answer (score 2):

Leave the primary key "CustomerId" out of select portion of your query... It should be auto generated for you on the inserted rows.

```
INSERT INTO Customer (FirstName, LastName)
(SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM Customer
WHERE LastName LIKE '%JONES%')
```